# What classspath is used for executing Grails' application.groovy

Tags: grails, grails3

**What classspath is used for compiling/executing Grails' application.groovy?**

In my application.groovy, I instantiate a custom class (contained in a dependency's jar) and assign it to one of the config properties, like so:

```
environments {
    production {
        configProperty = new com.example.CustomClass()
```

I recently upgraded my application from Grails 3.1.5 to 3.2.2, and now this no longer works.

I receive an error like the following when I try to run `grails run-app`:

```
Error occurred running Grails CLI: startup failed:
script14788250424471597489853.groovy: 43: unable to resolve class com.example.CustomClass
 @ line 43, column 33.
        configProperty = new com.example.CustomClass()
```

(Notice that the code is in the `production` block, but I'm running in development (`run-app`). That makes me think it's the compilation of this script that is failing.)

So I'm guessing I just need to add my dependency (that contains the `CustomClass`) to the appropriate classpath, but I'm not sure which one.

I'm using gradle, and have the following in my build.gradle file, to pull in the dependency containing `CustomClass`:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.example:custom-module:1.1"
// ...
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.example', name: 'custom-module', version:'1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `grails-app/conf/application.groovy` file shouldn't reference application classes because it is read before compilation. If you wish to reference application classes in configuration please use `grails-app/conf/runtime.groovy`

Comment: Thanks. Is that documented anywhere? [This search](https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&btnG=Search&q=grails+runtime.groovy#q=grails+%2B%22runtime.groovy%22) didn't turn up any results.

Comment: The `runtime.groovy` file appears to be executed in the same way as `application.groovy`. See [`GroovyConfigPropertySourceLoader.load()`](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-core/src/main/groovy/org/grails/core/cfg/GroovyConfigPropertySourceLoader.groovy).